# How to Ignore javascript outgoing calls in Gecko Driver?

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, web-scraping, geckodriver

I am **scraping** a web page, but first I have to execute javascript code. In the browser page loads quickly, but in selenium it takes some time. So trying to ignore any unnecessary operations. I would like to ignore any outgoing calls in javascript, is that possible? I am using GeckoDriver 0.26.0

Comment: do you use adblocking extensions in your browser ? If so, then use the same while executing the gecko driver.

Comment: No, i'm not using any adblocker.